# node.js global array vs redis

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, redis

I am building a node.js application and have a set of attributes that I need to look up on every action (they are associated with permissions).  I am using a mysql database as my persistant storage.   I was initially going to use redis to store these attributes as they don't change that much and so can be loaded from the mysql database when the application is started and refreshed if they ever change.  The point being that I need the lookup to be quick as possible since it happens often, but the data doesn't need to persist so redis instead of mysql.

As I was thinking about this today, it occurred to me that I could maybe use a global associative array to store this data.  I am always going to be looking things up by the same key and always getting the full list of attributes. I figure that when I start the application on the server, it can just load the data into an array attached to the "global" object in node rather than sticking it into redis so I can reduce the complexity of the app stack.   Plus I'm assuming that the javascript array would be a faster lookup as well since it's less overhead.

Am I missing something?  Is there something about the way either redis or the global object in node works that would make the former faster?   I anticipate the most likely situation would be 100's of keys but there could be situations where I could have 10000's.   That still doesn't seem too big in the grand   scheme of things though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the data in a global object will definitely be faster since there is no network overhead, parsing overhead, etc. The only problem (in your scenario) is that it will take more memory since you'll have a copy in each process. If that's not a problem then go for it.

Comment: Will it really take more memory?   Isn't node single threaded and thus there will only really be the one copy of that global array?   As I understand the way callbacks work, the "state" of the function is essentially saved so that when the callback function gets triggered, all the variables local to that function get reloaded.   But the global variables are outside the local scope and so don't get "frozen".   Meaning that there is only one copy that all the callbacks would share.   does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, but that's assuming that you only have one NodeJS process. I'm not sure what kind of application you are writing but I assume it's an http server. If that's correct then generally you want to run more then 1 backend process so that you can utilize multiple cores/machines. You will have a copy in each process while using Redis you will only keep it in one place.